# Data Binding so that changing a TextBox value updates the LIstBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to get data updates to work both into and out of XAML. I.e, when I make a change in the XAML TextBox the C# will receive the new value and when I change the C# (simulated by clicking a button), both the XAML TextBox changes. I have got this to work, however if I make a change to the XAML TextBox it doenst update the XAML ItemsList. Any ideas how I can get this working?

MainWindow.xaml...

```
<Window x:Class="MySimpleProgram.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="725"
        >
    <StackPanel Name="StackPanel1" Orientation="Horizontal">

        <TextBox Name="TextBox2" Text="{Binding Path=FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="23"/>

        <Button Name="Button1" Content="Change C# obj people[0]" Width="175" Height="20" Click="Button1_Click" />

        <ListBox Name="listPeople" DisplayMemberPath="FirstName"/>

    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private String _FirstName;

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _FirstName; }
        set
        {
            _FirstName = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(
                    this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("FirstName"));
        }
    }

    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public Person[] people;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        people = new Person[]{ 
            new Person{ FirstName = "Shirley", Age = 22 }, 
            new Person{ FirstName = "Roy", Age = 29 }, 
            new Person{ FirstName = "Manuel", Age = 34 } };

        StackPanel1.DataContext = people[0];

        listPeople.ItemsSource = people;
    }


    private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        people[0].FirstName += "y";
    }

}
```

Comment: why does your stackpanel have data context to the first item of the list? StackPanel1.DataContext = people[0];

Comment: probably it does not work because of that. look in to your debug window to see data binding errors...

Comment: Thanks @bjoshi, I dont get any errors, what should I set it to?

Comment: it seems you need to handle the first item differently of your list, in that case its my bad you can set the datacontext to first item then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set **`UpdateSourceTrigger`** to **`PropertyChanged`** on your TextBox binding.

Default value is **`LostFocus`** i.e. *source updates on lost focus but in case you want updation when you typing in set it to PropertyChanged.* and you will see update in ListBox.

```
<TextBox Name="TextBox2"
         Text="{Binding Path=FirstName, Mode=TwoWay,
                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         Height="23"/>
```